# I got error when I run python manage.py makemigrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, python-venv

When I run python manage.py makemigrations

I got this error:

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-136:~/easy_django_repo$ python manage.py makemigrations
/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:143: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Scribe3501"
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Scribe3501"

  warnings.warn(
No changes detected
```

This is my database in setting.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "Uninsured4645",
        "USER": "Scribe3501",
        "PASSWORD": "****",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": ''
    }
}
```

I tried to reset my password with:

```
CREATE USER ubuScribe3501t WITH PASSWORD '****';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is your user password which you are creating...
It seems your db password is incorrect check if you are connecting with right database

Comment: I tried next command and change password of setting.py, but there comes same erro.

[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `postgres=# ALTER ROLE Scribe3501 WITH PASSWORD '#####';`

Comment: @ShunNada ALTER USER Scribe3501 WITH PASSWORD '#####'; if this doesn't work for you try creating new database with new user

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I created new database but it didn't work for me. I think my problem was I didn't use postges password properly. And I still haven't solved it.